# Named Mercurial branch branched off too late. Start anonymous branch and close head or revert the changes in content but not in structure?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, branch

We are currently working on a project to benchmark a program on different architectures. Most of the codebase is identical and an early version runs on all architectures. We discovered some architecture-specific optimizations and branched off one version in a named branch. However, this happened too late.

The commit tree looks like this:

```
  A
  |
  B
 / \
 C D
 | |
 \ /
  M
 / \
H   \
     P
```

At commit B, the then-anonymous branches diverged and were merged in commit M. We noticed that optimizations good for one architecture are detrimental for the second one and decided to keep the architecture-specific changes in a name branch with current head P. 
D introduced some bugs which break unit tests, this was discovered after merging in M. To continue locally I reverted most of the changes in H and Commits B and H are almost identical.
I am currently at head H and noticed that the changes introduced by B are already optimized for the architecture I'm not working on.

I would now like to continue with the code from commit A, but make it as easy as possible to transplant further algorithmic changes to P. As I see it, the following options exist:

- Start anonymous branch at A, close head at H. (cleanest, structure follows content)
- Copy files manually from A to H and commit. (Avoids increasing the number of heads, makes updating to the current tip easier)
- Start new named branch.

Which option conforms to current best practices? Are there any other options?

Comment: I finally created a new anonymous branch.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can continue with H and revert (some or all) files to the revision as found in A: `hg up H; hg revert -rA FILENAME; hg commit -m "Restore generally useable state for FILENAME"`

Or you can backout single changesets: `hg up H; hg backout D`

However that you now created an anonymous branch based on A is not a bad decision either.